# OracleCommand parameters added but exception is thrown

Tags: c#, oracle, parameters

Could you please be patient to look through the codes I'm going to write below. I have 2 methods:

```
     public void AddInParameters(string parameterName, OracleDbType dbtype,
                                                                 object value)
    {
        OracleParameter myparameter = new OracleParameter();
        myparameter.ParameterName = parameterName;
        myparameter.OracleDbType = dbtype;
        myparameter.Value = value;
        myparameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        this._parameters.Add(myparameter);
    }
```

and

```
    public void AddOutParameter(string parameterName, OracleDbType dbType)
    {
        OracleParameter myparameter = new OracleParameter();
        myparameter.ParameterName = parameterName;
        myparameter.OracleDbType = dbType;
        myparameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        this._parameters.Add(myparameter);
    }
```

Private field _parameters is of type List. As you can see these methods create Input and Output parameters respectively and add them to the _parameters list. And then I have the following method that will take an OracleCommand and add all the parameters in the list to it:

```
     private void ProcessParameters(OracleCommand command)
    {
        foreach (OracleParameter myparameter in this._parameters)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(myparameter);
        }
    }
```

And here's my final method that returns an OracleDataReader:

```
   public OracleDataReader ExecuteReader(string commandText, CommandType commandType)
    {
        OracleDataReader returnValue = null;
        OracleCommand myCommand = this.CreateCommand(commandText, commandType);
        this.ProcessParameters(myCommand);
        try
        {

            myCommand.Connection.Open();
            returnValue = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new DatabaseException(ex.Message);
        }


        return returnValue;

    }
```

All these methods are in Data Access layer class library. In the class where I want to call ExcuteReader method I do the following in order:

1. I first add parameters using AddInParameters and AddOutparameters
2. Then I call ExecuteReader method.

But I sometimes get "wrong number or type of arguments" Oracle exception. If I refuse to use these methods ang go on using standard way (Creating a connection, then a command, then adding parameters one by one, opening the connection and finally caling OracleCommand.ExecuteReader method) I don't get that error. What is strange is I use these methods right at the entrance of my application but I've never gotten any exception there. I put a breakpoint to check for the list of parameters before the executeion of ExecuteReader method, everything seeems fine, I mean all the parameters are set right. Could you please tell me what I am missing here.

P.S. I use Oracle data Provider for .NET (Oracle.Data.Access.dll).

Comment: Read here: http://forums.asp.net/t/606602.aspx/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really feels so good to find the solution to a problem that took my 1.5 days. As I've already said, Oracle is a real headache. It's like an "I don't want this, I don't want that, I want it this way" girl. So many details, so many things that need to be taken into account. And those who go crazy about Oracle say that that's what makes Oracle robust.

After long fights and hopeless searches @Dummy01 suggested me to set OracleCommand.BindByName=true. I actually did not try it immediately. I looked up that property in ODP.NET documentation and look what I found:

***If the OracleCommand BindByName property is set to false (default), then
ODP.NET assumes that the parameters have been bound based on their position, and
all parameters have been specified in the correct order.***

So this means, if in stored procedure the parameters are in order of p1,p2,p3 you have to add those parameters to OracleCommand.Parameters in the same order. Otherwise 2 bad things can happen:

1. The better case is you get exception. Assume you pass them in the order of p1,p3,p2 and p2 is of type number and p3 is a refcursor. The stored procedure in the database expects the second parameter to be a number and the third one to be refcursor. But as the order of parameter passing is different from the original one the types will be incompatible thus will throw an exception. You are lucky if those types are different.
2. The second and the worse case is both p2 and p3 are of the same datatype. I'm sure you can guess what will happen:Yes, you'll enter wrong values for parameters and this will 99% cause a different result from what is expected.

   I hope anyone who deals with Oracle Stored procedures takes this into consideration, otherwise they can lose their jobs. Good luck

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to use `OracleCommand.BindByName = true`?

Comment: Yes, it did work after I tried what you suggested.You are a life saver. I'm going to write a detailed answer to my question based upon the hint you gave. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Mike JM Glad that I helped you. Please remember to accept the answer you prefer whenever you can.